# Swift class: Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I created a little convenience class for haptics and I try to reference the class in my Objc code:

`self.haptics = [[Haptics new] initWithStyle:UIImpactFeedbackStyleLight];`

```
@objc final class Haptics: NSObject {

    private var feedbackGenerator: UIImpactFeedbackGenerator? = nil

    init?(style: UIImpactFeedbackStyle) {
        guard UserFeedback.soundsAndVibrationsEnabled() else { return nil }

        self.feedbackGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: style)
    }

    func prepare() {
        feedbackGenerator?.prepare()
    }

    func hit() {
        feedbackGenerator?.impactOccurred()
    }

}
```

I get a crash on the Haptics class declaration:

> Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'MyProject.Haptics'

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 2):

```
[Haptics new]
```

is a short form for

```
[[Haptics alloc] init]
```

therefor init() without parameter is called, but it doesn't exist.

do

```
self.haptics = [[Haptics alloc] initWithStyle:UIImpactFeedbackStyleLight];
```